# Put ResultSet into HashMap?

Tags: java, database, resultset

I have an mySQL ResultSet and I want to store that in my HashMap:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Gets the Result set here then:

```
while(rs.next()){                           
    rs.put("Column1","Column2");
}
```

This is not right, could some explain the correct way to do it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, it would be something like:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
...
// parsing the column each time is a linear search
int column1Pos = rs.findColumn("Column1");
int column2Pos = rs.findColumn("Column2");
while (rs.next()) {
    String column1 = rs.getString(column1Pos);
    int column2 = rs.getInt(column2Pos);
    myMap.put(column1, column2);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use column name directly to get data from ResultSet ?

Comment: As I know, it's possible to write directly `rs.getString("Column1")` instead of  `rs.getString(column1Pos);`

Comment: Sorry, you are correct @O.Badr  I'm not sure why the user wanted it.

Answer (score 17):

```
 List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Map map = new HashMap();
            for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                String key = meta.getColumnName(i);
                String value = rs.getString(key);
                map.put(key, value);
            }
            list.add(map);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a `Map<YourKeyType, Map<String, Integer>>`.

So you are mapping each row by id (whatever type that is) to a map of column/value.  Here I assumed every column was Integer since that's what you had in your question, but you could use Object if they differ.  Then you could access the values with `myMap.get(myId).get( "column1" );` or walk it using the keySet() or whatever you need to do with it.

To populate the map, you would do something like

```
Map<KeyType, Map<String, Object>> resultMap = new HashMap<KeyType, Map<String, Object>>();
while( rs.next()) {
    Map<String, Object> tmpMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    tmpMap.put( "Column1", rs.get( "Column1" );
    // etc. for other columns
    resultMap.put( rs.get( "id" ), tmpMap );
}
```